# Can't get rid of trash while overloading operator << in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

```
class point //declaration of class
{
    private:
    int x, y;
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &input, point &p);
    public:
    //constructors and some other methods
};

//definition of overloading <<
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &input, point &p)
{
    input << std::cout << "x = " << p.x << " y = " << p.y << " ";
    return input;
}
```

And it works but when I use it

```
std::cout << object;
```

it shows some trash before my text:

```
062ACC3E8x = 1 y = 22
```

So 062ACC3E8X is something that always appears. It is defferent if I restart Visual Studio which I'm working on, so I suppose It's some memory adress. How to get rid of it? Is it something missing or wrong in my code?

Comment: `input << std::cout <<` WTF? Typing random stuff without understanding how it works isn't going to take you far...

Comment: It wasn't typing random stuff, just a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `std::cout` into your output stream. Change your code to:

```
//definition of overloading <<
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &input, point &p)
{
    input << "x = " << p.x << " y = " << p.y << " ";
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked. Now just for sure. What was I doing with passing std::cout into stream? Was it adress? What to?

Answer (score 3):

You output some adress, since `std::ostream` has [implicit void* conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

> 1) Returns a null pointer if fail() returns true, otherwise returns a
>   non-null pointer. This pointer is implicitly convertible to bool and
>   may be used in boolean contexts.

Should be just

```
input << "x = " << p.x << " y = " << p.y << " ";
```

Comment: Yes, It works. Thank You for the explanation what was going there.